# Add non ASCII header to request okhttp3 throws unexpected char

Tags: android, kotlin, header, okhttp

I have first request:

```
val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://abracodabra.com")
            .header("A", "B")
            .header("C", "D")
            .build()
        Log.d("qwerty123", request.toString())
```

I'm trying to add new header with the value of non ASCII chars to the new request with okhttp3 in the following way:

```
val requestNew = request.newBuilder()
            .apply {
                header("E", "фыв") // throws exception Unexpected char
            }
            .build()
```

I got exception Unexpected char.

I found two solutions to solve this problem:

Solution 1 using addUnsafeNonAscii function:

```
val requestNew = request.newBuilder()
            .apply {
                //header("E", "фыв") // throws exception Unexpected char

                headers(
                    request.headers.newBuilder()
                        .addUnsafeNonAscii("E", "фыв")
                        .build()
                ) // Solution 1
            }
            .build()
```

Solution 2 using addHeaderLenient function:

```
val requestNew = request.newBuilder()
            .apply {
                //header("E", "фыв") // throws exception Unexpected char

                headers(
                    addHeaderLenient(request.headers.newBuilder(), "E", "фыв")
                        .build()
                ) // Solution 2
            }
            .build()
```

An my question is: how are these two solutions different and which one is better?

I assume that the solution 1 validates the header value allowing non ASCII chars, and the solution 2 does not perform any validation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfDeq.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbdSr.png)

Is there any better way to solve this problem?

I found these solutions in the following topics:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/7275
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2016